# Creation of JSON service to read/write HDFS data

Tags: java, json, scala, hadoop, hdfs

My requirement is as follows:

We are trying to implement **Recommendations Engine** for one of our customers. To achieve the same, we need to store data in HDFS from web application (for every click on the product) and compute the recommendations in the back end and display the result (as product) in the web application.

My approach is as follows highlighted with the steps:

1. We have downloaded and configured the Cloudera
2. We have downloaded/configured Apache Mlib (Recommendations Engine)
3. Using Eclipse Luna, we are able to run the Mlib (using Java plugin)
4. Now we need to create a JSON service which will read the data from web and
   store in the HDFS. We are stuck in this step.
5. Now we need to create a JSON service which can read the data from HDFS and 
   compute the Recommendations and display the result in JSON format dynamically.

**We are stuck at Step 4 & 5. Please suggest, how can we create a JSON service to read/write from HDFS?**

Comment: I'm only vaguely familiar with it, but this sounds like it might be a good use of Flume. Link: https://flume.apache.org/FlumeUserGuide.html

Comment: With the help of REST services we were able to fix the solution

Answer (score 0):

You asked a very general question. I suggest you to get familiar with Apache Spark first. Read it's quick [guide](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/quick-start.html). Start to read\write data from hdfs into jsonRDD as described in [tutorial](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#json-datasets). After you understand how to work with batch processing, read about [spark streaming](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-programming-guide.html).

There is an [old story](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclid#Life) that Ptolemy I asked if there was a shorter path to learning geometry than Euclid's Elements. Euclid replied there is no royal road to geometry. So there is no fast way to build mllib engine for your clients except for reading and understanding the basics of Apache Spark Usage. I wish you a good luck in that!

Comment: Is it possible to create RESTFUL webservice by which we can input the data from webapplication and store it in HDFS ?

Comment: Sure, use http endpoint for any streaming source you like. For example, https://github.com/stealthly/dropwizard-kafka-http

Comment: @AshaDatla HDFS has already a HTTP API called webhdfs: https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.0.4/webhdfs.html